# how to retrieve woocommerce product details based on their category_id using mysql -php

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I have to retrieve the product details such as image title,description,image link and price from woocommerce table.

I've retrieved the categories with this Query,

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT term_id,name,slug FROM wp_terms WHERE term_id 
    IN (SELECT term_id FROM wp_term_taxonomy WHERE parent='0' 
    AND taxonomy='product_cat') ORDER BY name ASC");
```

Based on this category id I'm retrieving the subcategories like this:

```
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT term_id,name,slug FROM wp_terms WHERE term_id
     IN (SELECT term_id FROM wp_term_taxonomy WHERE parent='$cat_id'
     AND taxonomy='product_cat') ORDER BY name ASC");
```

I've tried a query to get the product details,

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT  `ID`,`post_title`,`post_content`,`guid` FROM wp_posts WHERE
post_type='product' and post_status='publish' and ID IN(SELECT object_id
FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN('$cat_id') and 
term_taxonomy_id IN(SELECT term_taxonomy_id FROM wp_term_taxonomy 
where taxonomy='product_cat'))");
```

This is giving me the title and description when I execute it in `phpmyadmin` but when I give the same code in php and sending the response through `json` then it is giving me the empty response.

I think my query is not proper.

Kindly suggest me how to get the product details from woocommerce,am working with it for the first time.

Comment: Won't this return multiple products? What are you actually trying to do? You shouldn't need any SQL for this...

Comment: yes it will.I need a list of products.  along with its details.Am sending the response to my android app through `json`  and showing the items in mobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I've **DONE IT**

Here goes the procedure of steps:

```
    --->  get `id` of product from `wp_posts`
    --->  pass it as a `post_id` to `wp_postmeta` and get the `meta_value` where `meta_key`='_thumbnail_id'
    --->  now send this `meta_value` as `id` of the product to `wp_posts `
    --->  in the field `guid` we have the link of image of the product
```

To get the price of the product:

```
---> Send `id` as a `post_id` to `wp_postmeta` and get the `meta_value` where `meta_key`='_price'
```

`Product description` and `product title` are stored in the table `wp_posts` in the fields `post_title` and `post_excerpt` respectively.

I've executed all these queries separately. That's why I'm not adding them in this answer.I'll edit this answer once am done with `joins`

Happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you can just use a standard [`WP_Query()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) for this:

```
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'product', 
    'posts_per_page' => -1, 
    'product_cat' => $cat_id, 
);
$result = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time.Shall I Include wordpress function in php?

Comment: Yes, that's one option. Another option is to use the [WP REST API plugin](http://v2.wp-api.org/). You can do this same query, and it will automatically return JSON.

Comment: I guess it will get complicated @rnevius..isn't it possible with mysql query's.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
global $wpdb;
$products = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT *
                                FROM wp_posts
                                LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
                                LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON (wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
                                 WHERE wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = 60
                                 ROUP BY wp_posts.post_title");
```

You have to change the `WHERE wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = 60` depending on your category number like `WHERE wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = $cat_no` or something like that.